# What's the purpose of a Promise without an async operation?

Tags: javascript, promise, polymer

I found the following comment in a Polymer web component

https://github.com/PolymerElements/app-storage/blob/master/app-localstorage/app-localstorage-document.html

> app-localstorage-document is the reference implementation of an
>   element that uses `AppStorageBehavior`. Reading its code is a good way
>   to get started writing your own storage element.

So I started to read the code, but didn't understand why the author is using promises like this:

```
saveValue: function(key) {
    try {
      this.__setStorageValue(key, this.data);       
    } 
    catch (e) {
      return Promise.reject(e);
    }
    this.key = key;
    return Promise.resolve();
  }
```

The only idea I have is that I can use the then/catch notation of promises

```
saveValue(42)
  .then(() => saveValue(21))
  .catch(() => ...);
```

But what's the difference between the "classic" way

```
try {
  saveValue(42);
  saveValue(21);
} catch(e) {...}
```

Comment: Probably he's just programming against an interface that simply requires the function to return a promise.

Comment: …and the interface would do that to allow the implementer to implement async storage. Async in this case would be the "lowest common denominator" to cover all possible use cases.

Comment: As mentioned in the comments above, it's best to avoid throwing synchronous exceptions in an asynchronous method, or if there is a plan in the future to switch to an asynchronous api in the future.